# How should I interpret this code: select(-Segment, -Units01)

Tags: r, select

Im trying to get my head around this code, down below.

The part that can't figure out is line 3:

```
select(-Segment, -Units01) %>%
```

The assignment:

> Delete observations where “Department” has a missing value or the
>   value “-“. Delete columns that are  constants. Make an id-variable
>   that has the value 1 in line one and 2 in line 2 etc.

The code works, but I need to understand it.

```
Extra001 <- read_rds("data20171001.rda") %>%
  filter(!trimws(Department) %in% c(NA, "-", "")) %>%
  select(-Segment, -Units01) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())
```

I've googled and read amounts of documentations with no luck so far.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: `select(-Segment, -Units01)` means select all columns except for Segment and Units01

Comment: *"read amounts of documentations"* ... the documentation that comes with the package ([`?select`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html)) does state this, *"To drop variables, use -"*, grouped along with other useful functions for how to *find* specific columns (e.g., `starts_with`, `ends_with`, ...).

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood it.